# Porque o first-child está selecionando o elemento <p>?

Tags: html, css

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        :first-child {
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Este é um parágrafo.</p>
    <p>Este é um parágrafo.</p>
    <p>Este é um parágrafo.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

No exemplo acima o `first-child` está selecionando e aplicando uma borda no elemento `<body>` e no elemento `<p>` porque isso está acontecendo não era para apenas o elemento `body` receber a borda já que ele é o primeiro elemento filho do documento?

**Notem**: no *stackoverflow* não funciona tem que ser em um documento separado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisará identificar a qual elemento o first-child será aplicado.
Nesse caso, como você não especificou, ele aplicou ao body.

Tente o seguinte código:

```
p:first-child {
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
```

Nesse caso, será aplicado a borda, ao seu primeiro parágrafo.

---

Caso queira que sua borda seja aplicada ao body, experimente utilizar

```
body{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Mas porque isso ocorre do `first-child` aplicar a borda no elemento `<body>` e `<p>`?

Comment: @joãobatista eu acabei de testar aqui, e na realidade o acontece com o seu código é que por não estar especificado uma tag, ele irá aplicar a todos os primeiros filhos.

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child

Comment: Verdade! era isso mesmo, valeu!